# Sed - Insert multiline before a multiline pattern existing between 2 patterns

Tags: awk, sed, insert, pattern-matching

I tried using `sed` to insert `$new` before `$orig` lying between `$Initial` and `$Final` as follows:

```
Initial="# Introduction"; \
Final="# External links"; \
orig="\n#(.*)\n"; \
new="\n<p><a href="#top" accesskey="t">[Top]</a></p>"; \
file="Input.md"; \
sed -i -r -e "\!$Initial!,\!$Final!!^$orig!i $new!g" $file ; \
```

### Note: I have used `^` so that the pattern begins at position 0

Input file:

```
# Dummy

# Introduction

-

# Summary

-

### See also

-

## References

-

# External links

# Dummy
```

---

Expected Output File:

```
# Dummy

# Introduction

-

<p><a href="#top" accesskey="t">[Top]</a></p>

# Summary

-

<p><a href="#top" accesskey="t">[Top]</a></p>

### See also

-

<p><a href="#top" accesskey="t">[Top]</a></p>

## References

-

<p><a href="#top" accesskey="t">[Top]</a></p>

# External links

# Dummy
```

---

The following substitution works (substitute between 2 patterns and against pattern):

```
Initial="# See also"; \
Final="# External links"; \
orig="\.\./(.*)\.md"; \
new="../../Rendered/\1.gen.pdf"; \
file="tempPDF.md"; \
sed -i -r -e "\!$Initial!,\!$Final!s!$orig!$new!g" $file ; \
```

I know that insert syntax is

```
sed -i '/pattern/i TextToInsert ' inputfile
```

So I clubbed these 2 as stated before.

I think problem lies with `orig="\\n#(.*)\\n"; \` and with the syntax of sed in `sed -i -r -e "\!$Initial!,\!$Final!!^$orig!i $new!g" $file ; \`

Comment: 'doesn't work' is very vague... Please post the input/output of your attempts.   From a quick scan, you use nested quotes, which is likely part of your problem.

Comment: @HardcoreHenry Please see the edit

Comment: You should post the text you're changing, before and after the change (with the expected result, and your result).

Comment: I highly recommend you figure out how to do this **outside** of a makefile first and only tackle making it work inside a makefile after you've successfully got it working outside.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sed is for doing s/old/new, that is all. For anything else you should be using awk for simplicity, clarity, robustness, portability, etc.

Is this what you're trying to do (outside of a makefile)?

```
$ awk '
    f && /^#/ { print "<p><a href=\"#top\" accesskey=\"t\">[Top]</a></p>\n" }
    /^# Introduction/   { f=1 }
    /^# External links/ { f=0 }
    { print }
' file
# Dummy

# Introduction

-

<p><a href="#top" accesskey="t">[Top]</a></p>

# Summary

-

<p><a href="#top" accesskey="t">[Top]</a></p>

### See also

-

<p><a href="#top" accesskey="t">[Top]</a></p>

## References

-

<p><a href="#top" accesskey="t">[Top]</a></p>

# External links

# Dummy
```

If you want "in place editing" you can use `awk -i inplace ...` with GNU awk just like you can use `sed -i ...` with GNU sed.

Comment: Yes, that's correct. Is it recommended to put the code in a separate awk script and call inside Makefile? Does it make a difference?

Comment: I haven't used a makefile in years so I don't remember all the associated caveats. I do know there are some though (e.g. something about having to double-up `$`s?). So I don't know if there's anything in that awk script that requires special treatment inside a makefile - if there is I would expect it to be very minor and easily handled but you can either do whatever you have to do in makefiles to handle whatever it is or store the awk script in a separate file and invoke it as `awk -f script.awk file`.

Answer (score 1):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed -i -e '/^# External links/h;x;/^# Introduction/{x;/^#/i <p><a href="#top" accesskey="t">[Top]</a></p>\n' -e 'x};x;/^# Introduction/h' file
```

Use the hold space (an additional buffer) to flag when to insert the required lines. Set the flag on when `# Introduction` is encountered and off when `# External links`. When the flag is on insert two lines before any line beginning `#`.